# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items' - Keras, model.fit() error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make a variational autoencoder with Keras using a custom model.

Note that if I don't have a validation dataset it doesn't error! I believe this error is due to the validation loss logs but I can't manage to work it out.

This is my model:

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        # Train
        self.total_train_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_train_loss")
        self.recon_train_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="recon_train_loss")
        self.kl_train_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_train_loss")
        # Val
        self.total_val_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_val_loss")
        self.recon_val_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="recon_val_loss")
        self.kl_val_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_val_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_train_loss_tracker,
            self.recon_train_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_train_loss_tracker,
            self.total_val_loss_tracker,
            self.recon_val_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_val_loss_tracker
        ]
        
    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            x, y, weights = data

            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(x)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            ## Loss
            # reconstruction
            recon_loss = binary_crossentropy(x, reconstruction) # Shape = BATCH_SIZE
            # Weights on recon loss
            recon_train_loss = (weights * recon_loss) / K.sum(weights)
            recon_loss = K.mean(recon_loss, axis = 0)

            # KL
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = K.mean(K.sum(kl_loss, axis=1), axis=0)
            # Weights on KL Loss
            kl_loss = (weights * kl_loss) / K.sum(weights)
            kl_loss = K.mean(kl_loss, axis = 0)

            # Total
            total_loss = recon_loss + kl_loss

        # Step
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        
        # Log
        self.total_train_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.recon_train_loss_tracker.update_state(recon_loss)
        self.kl_train_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "total_train_loss": self.total_train_loss_tracker.result(),
            "recon_train_loss": self.recon_train_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_train_loss": self.kl_train_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def validation_step(self, data):
        # No tape, we don't need gradients
        x, y = data

        print("1", type(x), type(y))

        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(x)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        ## Loss
        # reconstruction
        recon_loss = binary_crossentropy(x, reconstruction) # Shape = BATCH_SIZE

        # KL
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = K.mean(K.sum(kl_loss, axis=1), axis=0)

        # Total
        total_loss = recon_loss + kl_loss


        loss = recon_loss*self.alpha + kl_loss

        # Log
        self.total_val_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.recon_val_loss_tracker.update_state(recon_loss)
        self.kl_val_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "total_val_loss": self.total_val_loss_tracker.result(),
            "recon_val_loss": self.recon_val_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_val_loss": self.kl_val_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        # No tape, we don't need gradients
        x, y = data

        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(x)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
        return reconstruction, z_mean, z_log_var, z # z is the latent vector

# Compile
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

And when I fit the model with:

```
## Callbacks
# Model name
name = str(datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S"))

# Tensorboard
TB = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=join("logs", name), write_images=True)

# Early Stopping
ES = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="total_val_loss", patience=30, verbose=2, mode="min")

# Model Checkpoint
MC = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=join("models_tf", name), save_best_only=True, monitor="total_val_loss", mode="min")

# Fit
history = vae.fit(
    # Train
    x=x_train, 
    y=x_train,
    sample_weight=x_train_weights,

    # Validation
    validation_data=(x_val,x_val),

    # Hyper-parameters    
    epochs=30, 
    batch_size=4048,
    callbacks=[TB, ES, MC])
```

It outputs:

```
Epoch 1/30
90/92 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - total_train_loss: -1.3369 - recon_train_loss: -1.3404 - kl_train_loss: 0.0035
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b3ea8a6b1b64> in <module>
      1 # Fit
----> 2 history = vae.fit(
      3     # Train
      4     x=x_train,
      5     y=x_train,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1212                 model=self,
   1213                 steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
-> 1214           val_logs = self.evaluate(
   1215               x=val_x,
   1216               y=val_y,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, return_dict, **kwargs)
   1494               callbacks.on_test_batch_end(end_step, logs)
   1495       logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
-> 1496       callbacks.on_test_end(logs=logs)
   1497 
   1498       if return_dict:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in on_test_end(self, logs)
    543     logs = self._process_logs(logs)
    544     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 545       callback.on_test_end(logs)
    546 
    547   def on_predict_begin(self, logs=None):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in on_test_end(self, logs)
   2391     if self.model.optimizer and hasattr(self.model.optimizer, 'iterations'):
   2392       with summary_ops_v2.record_if(True), self._val_writer.as_default():
-> 2393         for name, value in logs.items():
   2394           summary_ops_v2.scalar(
   2395               'evaluation_' + name + '_vs_iterations',

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I'm currently using Keras and tensorflow 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items' and thanks to you, I solved it.
The problem was at the end of `train_step()`, I returned `return d_loss, g_loss, generated_images`, which resolved to a touple with then threw the Error.
Instead, I returned a dict:
`return {'d_loss': d_loss, 'g_loss': g_loss, 'generated_images': generated_images}` and it worked.
So looking at your code, in `test_step()` you just return a touple instead of a dict.
Hope this is helpful